iOS: how to start a web search using the default web browser and the default search engine
In my app, I would like to search for a query using the user-set default web browser and the default search engine.
iOS itself is able to do that from a few places, one of which being the menu available on text selection. Here's a screenshot below:

What would be the x-url-scheme or deep link to do such thing outside this system-provided menu, in a custom button for instance?
I currently use x-web-search://?<query> but it will only start a search in Safari.
I don't want to have to offer a menu where users can set their preferred web browser and search engine inside my app. I would like to use the system-wide setting.

You can add your custom menu that pops up when text is selected. Then you can add action "Search Web" inside it.
For example, if you are using UITextView, you can set:
textView.addInteraction(UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self))

When you inherit UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate in your viewController, you can add this function to set show the UIMenu with "Search Web" option:
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let searchAction = UIAction(title: "Search Web", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")) { [weak self] action in
        if let selectedText = self?.textView.text(in: self?.textView.selectedTextRange ?? UITextRange()) {
            self?.searchWeb(for: selectedText)
        }
    }
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
        return UIMenu(title: "", children: [searchAction])
    }
}

Then in a searchWeb(), you can call UIApplication.shared.open(url... which should open a webpage in the default browser.

Thank you for your reply! I probably explained this poorly, but I am not looking for how to implement a UIContextMenuInreraction but to find the url scheme that would allow me to do a web search using both the default browser and the default search engine.
